# Why does my call to file.WriteLine() fail to write all contents of the StringBuilder to the file?

Tags: c#, file-io, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I'm trying to write an html file to disk via a StringBuilder and File.WriteLn(), but the file is written lacking a few lines, and is thus useless. My code is:

```
    private void BuildAndWriteHTMLFile()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    sb.Append("<html lang=\"en\">");
    sb.Append("<head>");
    sb.Append("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
    sb.Append("<title>Green Bay Packers 2013 Schedule (All times Central)</title>");
    sb.Append("<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js\"></script> ");
    sb.Append("<script src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\"></script> ");
    sb.Append("<script src=\"gomap.js\"></script> ");
    sb.Append("<!--[if IE]>");
    sb.Append("<script src=\"http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js\"></script>");
    sb.Append("<![endif]-->");

. . . // oodles on noodly code elided for lack of reason to leave it in

    sb.Append("this.singleMarker = false;");
    sb.Append("this.lockGeocode = false;");
    sb.Append("this.markers = [];");
    sb.Append("this.tmpMarkers = [];");
    sb.Append("this.geoMarkers = [];");
    sb.Append("},");

    sb.Append("isVisible: function(latlng) {");
    sb.Append("return this.map.getBounds().contains(latlng);");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("})(jQuery);");

    sb.Append("$(function() {");

    sb.Append("$(\"#map\").goMap({ ");
    sb.Append("latitude: 36.75,  ");
    sb.Append("longitude: -100, ");
    sb.Append("maptype: 'ROADMAP',");
    sb.Append("zoom: 5");
    sb.Append("}); ");

    sb.Append("$.goMap.createMarker({");
    sb.Append("address: 'Green Bay, Wisconsin',");
    sb.Append("title: 'Lambeau Field, Green Bay, WI',");
    sb.Append("html: '<h1>Green Bay Packers Home Games</h1><p class=\"away\">Game 1, Week 1) Sunday Sept. 8 at SAN FRANCISCO 49ERS  3:25 p.m.</p><p>Game 2, Week 2) Sunday Sept. 15 WASHINGTON REDSKINS Noon</p><p class=\"away\">Game 3, Week 3) Sunday Sept. 22 at CINCINNATI BENGALS Noon</p><p>Game 4, Week 5) Sunday Oct. 6    DETROIT LIONS       Noon</p><p class=\"away\">Game 5, Week 6) Sunday Oct. 13 at BALTIMORE RAVENS        Noon</p><p>Game 6, Week 7) Sunday Oct. 20   CLEVELAND BROWNS    3:25 p.m.</p><p class=\"away\">Game 7, Week 8) Sunday Oct. 27 at MINNESOTA VIKINGS  7:30 p.m.</p><p>Game 8, Week 9) Monday Nov. 4   CHICAGO BEARS       7:40 p.m.</p><p>Game 9, Week 10) Sunday Nov. 10 PHILADELPHIA EAGLES     Noon</p><p class=\"away\">Game 10, Week 11) Sunday Nov. 17 at NEW YORK GIANTS   7:30 p.m. (flex)</p><p>Game 11, Week 12) Sunday Nov. 24 MINNESOTA VIKINGS   Noon (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">Game 12, Week 13) Thursday Nov. 28 at DETROIT LIONS    11:30 a.m.  </p><p>Game 13, Week 14) Sunday Dec. 8  ATLANTA FALCONS     7:30 p.m. (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">Game 14, Week 15) Sunday Dec. 15 at DALLAS COWBOYS    3:25 p.m. (flex)</p><p>Game 15, Week 16) Sunday Dec. 22 PITTSBURGH STEELERS 3:25 p.m. (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">Game 16, Week 17) Sunday Dec. 29 at CHICAGO BEARS Noon (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">SUPER BOWL Sunday Feb. 2, 2014 vs ?</p>'");
    //sb.Append("html: '<h1>Green Bay Packers Home Games</h1><p class=\"away\">Game 1, Week 1) Sunday Sept. 8 at SAN FRANCISCO 49ERS    3:25 p.m.</p><p>Game 2, Week 2) Sunday Sept. 15 WASHINGTON REDSKINS Noon</p><p class=\"away\">Game 3, Week 3) Sunday Sept. 22 at CINCINNATI BENGALS Noon</p><p>Game 4, Week 5) Sunday Oct. 6    DETROIT LIONS       Noon</p><p class=\"away\">Game 5, Week 6) Sunday Oct. 13 at BALTIMORE RAVENS        Noon</p><p>Game 6, Week 7) Sunday Oct. 20   CLEVELAND BROWNS    3:25 p.m.</p><p class=\"away\">Game 7, Week 8) Sunday Oct. 27 at MINNESOTA VIKINGS  7:30 p.m.</p><p>Game 8, Week 9)");
    //sb.Append("Monday Nov. 4  CHICAGO BEARS       7:40 p.m.</p><p>Game 9, Week 10) Sunday Nov. 10 PHILADELPHIA EAGLES     Noon</p><p class=\"away\">Game 10, Week 11) Sunday Nov. 17 at NEW YORK GIANTS   7:30 p.m. (flex)</p><p>Game 11, Week 12) Sunday Nov. 24 MINNESOTA VIKINGS   Noon (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">Game 12, Week 13) Thursday Nov. 28 at DETROIT LIONS    11:30 a.m.  </p><p>Game 13, Week 14) Sunday Dec. 8  ATLANTA FALCONS     7:30 p.m. (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">Game 14, Week 15) Sunday Dec. 15 at DALLAS COWBOYS    3:25 p.m. (flex)</p><p>Game 15, Week 16)");
    //sb.Append("Sunday Dec. 22 PITTSBURGH STEELERS 3:25 p.m. (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">Game 16, Week 17) Sunday Dec. 29 at CHICAGO BEARS Noon (flex)</p><p class=\"away\">SUPER BOWL Sunday Feb. 2, 2014 vs ?</p>'");
    sb.Append("});");

    sb.Append("});");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    sb.Append("</body>");
    sb.Append("</html>");

    string nameOfFile = string.Format(@"C:\misc\mapcode_{0}", GetFileNameDateTimeExtension());
    if (!File.Exists(nameOfFile))
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@nameOfFile);
        file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        urlOfGeneratedFile = string.Format("file:///{0}", nameOfFile);
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(urlOfGeneratedFile);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the file that is written is a truncated version of what's in the StringBuilder. It first truncated the last few lines that had been appended (with the written file ending on "*NEW YORK G*"); when I commented out the last createMarker section just prior to the closing script, body, and html tags, the file ended a little above that on "*this.lockGeocode = false;this.markers = [];this.tmpMarkers = [];this.geoM*"

It's as if the write to file is being done before all the lines have been written to the StringBuilder.

Do I need to call Flush, or a Sleep method, or what?

Comment: What happens if/when you wrap the StreamWriter in a using block. The dispose should flush the stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not closing/disposing of the StreamWriter, the writer has a internal buffer that is not written out till you close the stream. Wrap the writer in a `using` statment to automaticly close the file when done.

```
if (!File.Exists(nameOfFile))
{
    using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@nameOfFile))
    {
        file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
    urlOfGeneratedFile = string.Format("file:///{0}", nameOfFile);
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(urlOfGeneratedFile);

}
```

However, your code could be simplied to just not use a `StreamWriter` and instead just call [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (!File.Exists(nameOfFile))
{
    File.WriteAllText(@nameOfFile,sb.ToString());
    urlOfGeneratedFile = string.Format("file:///{0}", nameOfFile);
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(urlOfGeneratedFile);

}
```

**UPDATE**: Actually, there will be a slight difference with `File.WriteAllText`, the `file.WriteLine` will add a extra newline at the end of the text, `File.WriteAllText` will not. If it is important to you that the newline is there add a `sp.AppendLine();` before you call `File.WriteAllText`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work as expected if you use a using block for your StreamWriter.

```
using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@nameOfFile)) 
  file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
urlOfGeneratedFile = string.Format("file:///{0}", nameOfFile);
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(urlOfGeneratedFile);
```

Otherwise, yes, use `StreamWriter.Flush` or set `StreamWriter.AutoFlush` to true.